# jquery load xml and set colors for negative and positive values

Tags: jquery, xml

The problem:

1. I have an withsomexml.php which contains xml on server A

   something
    SomeName
    111.196
    etc. etc
2. I need to display these values on another site on server B with refresh function
   What I have now:

**--> index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('getXML.php', function(data) {
        $(data).find('index').each(function(){
        $("#test").html('<div class="myclass1">ID:' +   $(this).find("id").text() + 
                            '</div><div class="myclass2">NAME:' + $(this).find("name").text() + 
                            '</div><div class="myclass3">KURS:' + $(this).find("kurs").text() + 
                            '</div>');
           });

        });
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"><div class="loader"><img src="loader.gif" id="load" width="50" height="50" align="absmiddle"/></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**--> getXML.php**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.xxxxxx.com/withsomexml.php');
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

So far it works good.
But now I don't have idea, how to set/change or adjust the text color.  If the kurs value is negative/red positive/green (kurs and 2 more numeric values), this solution `$("#div:contains('-')").addClass('red');` does not work.

I appreciate any help, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

$("div div:contains('-')").addClass('red');

this is the code below

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/devog/2/edit)